# what's the meaning of error message with ipython in spark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I have successfully install spark1.6 and Anaconda2. When I try to use ipython, I got the problem as following:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.

: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost):
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/root/anaconda2/bin": error=13,Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047) at     org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 14 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:393)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/root/anaconda2/bin": error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 14 more
```

The ipython code I use as following, And I got the error when I coded the last line.

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint, LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel
```

## Load and parse the data

```
def parsePoint(line):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')]
    return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[1:])

data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/ridge-data/lpsa.data")
parsedData = data.map(parsePoint)
```

## Build the model   error occurred

```
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, iterations=100, step=0.00000001)
```

Comment: Please give us more information. Which system are you using(windows ,linux or OSX)? Installation directory of Anaconda ? If linux, then probably you have used sudo while installing Anaconda ( sudo bash Anaconda.xx.sh) due to which it is asking for root's permission.

Comment: The system I use is Linux-Centos. I install the Anaconda in root user desktop. I installed the anaconda as a root user. And I use this command as root user.

Comment: How did you run your above code? From notebook, from pyspark shell, or spark-submit? What is your `PYSPARK_PYTHON` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to first remove the anaconda distribution

```
sudo -r rm anaconda_installation_path
```

Then, install it without sudo

```
sh Anaconda.xx.sh
```

For more information visit [page](https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/install-python-2-7-centos-anaconda/).

Answer (score 0):

reinstall anaconda, put anaconda in /opt/anaconda directory solve my problm